# preencher tabela com javascript e ajax!

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estou tentando preencher uma tabela utilizando javascript com os dados advindos de um modelo ajax. 
dessa forta :

```js
$("#md").on("click", function() {
                if (FA.checked) {
                    $("div.hidden").css('display', 'block');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/treino",
                        method: "GET",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function(resp) {
                            $('#score1').append(resp.scoreF);                    
                        }
                    })

                }
            })
```

O codigo funciona! , quando eu aperto o botão a minha tabela em html adiciona o valor esperado no local esperando com a função do append , o problema é que quando eu aperto novamente o botão a tabela adiciona o valor novamente , ficando dois valores um ao lado do outro , eu gostaria de uma função que simplesmente substituísse um valor pelo outro !

Comment: Complicado te ajudar porque o erro é local, você precisa nos mostrar com um exemplo minimo, somente esse código não nos ajuda a te ajudar!

Comment: Obrigado por responder , vou tentar reformular a pergunta sendo mais claro e objetivo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função **[.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)** serve para acrescentar conteúdo. No seu caso, se quer colocar um conteúdo substituindo, por ventura, algum que já exista, pode usar uma de duas funções, dependendo do conteúdo retornado pelo AJAX:

**[.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/)**: se o conteúdo possui código HTML ou texto puro, ou

**[.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)**: se o conteúdo possui apenas texto puro.

Então seria `$('#score1').html(resp.scoreF);` ou `$('#score1').text(resp.scoreF);`, dependendo do retorno que espera no AJAX,

Comment: Obrigado , deu certo !